# Laravel - using CacheManager as a dependency

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I am trying to use `CacheManager` class as a dependency in my service:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager;

class MatrixWebService implements WebServiceInterface
{
    public function __construct(Client $client, CacheManager $cache)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}
```

Because there can be multiple implementations of `WebserviceInterface` I need to define it in the `AppServiceProvider` accordingly:

```
$this->app->bind(WebServiceInterface::class, function () {
    return new MatrixWebService(
        new Client(),
        $this->app->get(CacheManager::class)
    );
});
```

The problem is when I am trying to use my service, Laravel is not able to resolve `CacheManager` class (there is some substitution for `cache` instead):

```
[2018-07-02 22:45:26] local.ERROR: Class cache does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class cache does not exist at /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:769)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(769): ReflectionClass->__construct('cache')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(648): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('cache')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(610): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('cache')
#3 /var/www/html/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(28): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->get('Illuminate\\\\Cach...')
...
```

Any ideas on how to approach this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your application has multiple implementations of an interface, [contextual binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#contextual-binding) is useful:

```
namespace App;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Cache\Repository;

class MatrixWebService implements WebServiceInterface
{
    public function __construct(Client $client, Repository $cache)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->cache = $cache;
    }
}

// AppServiceProvider.php
public function register()
{
     $this->app->bind(WebServiceInterface::class, MatrixWebServiceInterface::class);

     // bind MatrixWebService
     $this->app->when(MatrixWebService::class)
               ->needs(Repository::class)
               ->give(function () {
                   return app()->makeWith(CacheManager::class, [
                       'app' => $this->app
                   ]);
               });

     // bind some other implementation of WebServiceInterface
     $this->app->when(FooService::class)
               ->needs(Repository::class)
               ->give(function () {
                   return new SomeOtherCacheImplementation();
               });
}
```

Comment: Can you please change `use Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository;` to `Cache\Repository` and add `$this->app->bind(WebServiceInterface::class, MatrixWebServiceInterface::class);` before `MatrixWebService` definition? I will accept the answer then.

Comment: Currently just using it for different environments. But will definitely use it in the future. Thanks!